# Juicer.io embed JS breaks Bootsrap tooltips

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I'm trying to embed a Juicer.io social feed on a page that uses bootstrap tooltips. For some reason, loading the juicer embed JS (//assets.juicer.io/embed.js) breaks the JS that initializes tooltips for Bootstrap. That code, straight from bootstrap, is:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

See example at http://supplybank.creativeforthepeople.org/about/our-story

The error I'm getting is, "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function." I've tried loading them in different orders, with no luck. Any idea why this is happening or how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Juicer JS is also including jQuery, which is causing this error. You will need to use the no-jquery version of the script instead:

```
<script src="//assets.juicer.io/embed-no-jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```